# Creating a button in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create some buttons in JQuery, and insert them into the existing html code. At the moment my code looks like this: 
I did not know how to select the second section of the page, so i selected the first and then the next of it. It don't know if that is possible, please be gentle there.

**EDIT**: Section is not only the name of the section html tag here, but also the class name in the code. Thats why i tried to select it with a class selector.

```
var addsection = $(".Section").first();
addsection = addsection.next();

var buttonline2 = ("<div></div>");
buttonline2.addClass("Grid-full");
var button3 = ("<div>Show all!</div>");
button3.addClass("Button");
var button4 = ("<div>Hide all!</div>");
button4.addClass("Button");
buttonline2.add(button1);
buttonline2.add(button2);

button3.click(function () { // Show all
    addresses.show();
});

button4.click(function () { // Hide all
    addresses.hide();
});

addsection.append(buttonline2);
```

The problem is that nothing is shown on my page. I dont know what i am doing wrong. On the forums and here on stackoverflow people kept telling to other questions that you simply need to append the part you want to have in your html. It does not show up in my html code either.
Please help :(

Comment: `button3`, `button4`, and `buttonline2` are literally only strings here. jQuery methods for elements would work correctly on them.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek They aren't strings, jQuery allows for that.

Comment: So what do i need to do? Is there any trick how i can tell the button to well.. be a button? I do not want to change my html code, or to make a button tag there. I really would like to be able to solve this by only using JQuery.

Comment: @Hitmands No they *are* just strings. All the methods intended for jQuery elements use would not work (meant to say *wouldn't above*) because they are strings. The first error in the console is `buttonline2.addClass is not a function` because a string doesn't have the function `addClass`. OP has: `("string here")`, not `$("string here")`.

Comment: @Hitmands OP  literally has strings, not jquery instances. `var buttonline2 = ("<div></div>"); console.log(typeof buttonline2);` :)

Comment: yep, he did `(String)` instead of `jQuery(String)` but this is just a oversight

Comment: @Hitmands and Spencer Wieczorek was pointing that out originally.

Comment: Oh my, i really did NOT see that i was missing the $. Wow. This is really devastating. Thank you guys a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is almost correct, please, follow this example:

```js
var buttonline2 = $("<div />", {
  class: 'Grid-full'
});


var button3 = $("<button />", {
    text: 'Show All!',
    class: 'Button'
  })
  .click(function () { // Show all
    console.log('let\'s show them all');
  })
  .appendTo(buttonline2)
;

var button4 = $("<button />", {
    text: 'Hide All!',
    class: 'Button'
  })
  .click(function () { // Hide all
    console.log('let\'s hide them all');
  })
  .appendTo(buttonline2)
;

$('#result').append(buttonline2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it definitely is working now. Definitely gonna triple check if i got all the $ in the future too.